# What is the ruling on causing another to leave Islam?

Tags: sin, apostasy

Asalamu alaikum,

I’d firstly like to say that this is a purely hypothetical question. I, nor anyone I know, has caused another to apostatise.

However, I have wondered about the ruling on this. Because in Islam, it’s pretty clear that you reap the positive consequences of your actions (gaining reward for building a mosque/ well/ tree etc).

So, I was wondering, if one was to cause another to leave Islam, would they then reap the sins of doing so?